# Tailwindcss text overflow

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I am making a code container for my website. It is working fine when the text does not need wrap. But I need to add a x-scrollbar if width is less than line width but my line is breaking to next line.

[tailwind play url](https://play.tailwindcss.com/ChN7ud7NH4)

**Note:** Resize the result container to see, any help is appreciated.
**Tried:** overflow-x-scroll and break-normal

Comment: You don't want to break lines the code block, that's it?

Comment: yes, in smaller screen the lines break but want them to overflow so as to add a scrollbar.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details. Please also read: [Can I just link to my website?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap your code block with [`pre`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) tag.

```html
      <pre>
def img2sketch(photo, k_size):
    img = cv2.imread(photo)
    grey_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    invert_img = cv2.bitwise_not(grey_img)
    blur_img = cv2.GaussianBlur(invert_img, (k_size, k_size) ,0)
    invblur_img = cv2.bitwise_not(blur_img)
    sketch_img = cv2.divide(grey_img,invblur_img, scale = 256.0)
    cv2.imwrite('sketch.png', sketch_img)
    cv2.imshow('sketch image',sketch_img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print(f"Usage: {sys.argv[0]} &lt;filename&gt; &lt;k_size(Optional)&gt;"))
        exit(0)
    photo = sys.argv[1]
    k_size = sys.argv[2] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else 7
    img2sketch(photo, k_size)
      </pre>
```

You can also check on Tailwind Playground https://play.tailwindcss.com/x7cCCQcQPU

Comment: thanks a lot. any other changes except pre tag?

Comment: Nop, I only added the pre tag